# Pivot full text instead of counts - Excel

Tags: excel, vba, pivot

I'm trying to determine the most efficient/effective way to display specific rows from a central table on `sheet1` as text on `sheet2`.

I have setup a table that contains numerous events that is continually being used by multiple people. This sheet acts as a central database and is shared with multiple people who are all using it in real time.

I want to provide a table on `sheet2` that allows other users to view specific events from the central database. So I need to export specific values from `sheet1` to `sheet2`. I understand this can easily be done using a filter but the table on `sheet1` is constantly being used and it can't be disrupted.

**I can't just do a sort or filter on the `sheet1` table because it needs to be used by other parties at all times**

I really only need to view specific values from `sheet1` for the last month. I've got code the exports all rows based off a specific value entered into a designated column on `Sheet1`. But due to the size of the file Excel constantly crashes.

I then thought a pivot table may be easier and I wouldn't have to use VBA. Is it possible to pivot out specific rows as text, which can be grouped by date, e.g. month?

For instance, if I want to view all `['A's']` and `['X's']` from `Column B` from the last month as full text it would look like the following:

Central Database table `Sheet1`

```
   A   B  C   D
0 11/1 A Big Dog
1 10/1 X  1   2 
2 11/1 Y  Y   Y
3 1/2  A Big Cat
4 1/2  X  3   4 
5 1/2  Y  Y   Y
```

Output table `Sheet2`

```
   A  B  C   D
1 1/2 A Big Cat
2 1/2 X  3   4
```

Comment: A pivot table wouldn't be a good fit here - if you show your existing code someone might have suggestions for fixing it.

Comment: Why not just use a filter?

Comment: @ Ron Rosenfeld. That's how I originally conceptualised it. But that database is being continuously used by other parties. There needs to be a separate sheet that filters the data so the central database can be used without interruption.

Comment: @ Tim Williams. I can insert the `code` but It's redundant. Due to the large amount of data in central database it blows up `Excel` if I run a macro that copies over specific values. The file goes from around `5MB` to over `300MB` if i had in that code. I need something more flexible that only displays values from the last _n_ period of time.

Comment: First, if you'd use pivot table, you'd almost doubles the size of file because pivot table creates *cache* - it's a copy of your data. Second, you could use SQL to query data - it's very fast.

Comment: @JPA0888 : I'm surprised that you say the central database can't handle some of your queries.  What is it?  SQL Server or Access?  If it is an open source DB then you can set up replication to get your own instance at no cost.  Then you run your own queries on your own instance.  https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Replication_(computing)#Database_replication

Comment: Is `Sheet1` the "central database", or is it *connecting* to one?

Comment: Are the dates under A actual *dates* that Excel understands as such? i.e. is it possible to filter them with `MONTH(A) = MONTH(NOW)`? Or they're just strings and the "month" needs to be parsed out of them?

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. Sheet1 is the central database. The users entering in data need something simple like an Excel table.

Comment: @MathieuGuindon, The dates are formatted as such. I can filter via them but I still need to display values from the alst month without filtering.

Comment: What is the frequency of refresh of Sheet2? How often does the extract run?  Does Sheet2 start empty at the beginning of the month? or does Sheet2 contain a rolling 30-day span? Can Sheet2 be in a separate workbook, a different filename from Sheet1?  What front end do users have to insert new rows into Sheet1?  What is frequency of Insert? of Update? (of Delete?) for rows in Sheet1?

Comment: If Excel crashes because of the size of the data, it's high time to change to a database.

Comment: I think it would be better to have 2 files: 1central database, and then other workbook that queries the central database, where you can specify parameters like dates. You can connect 2 workbooks using SQL sentences and it would be easy to refresh (and also, you can set up an autorefresh timer). Check [How do I join two worksheets in Excel as I would in SQL?](https://superuser.com/a/421493)

Comment: @FunThomas, It only crashes upon transferring the data. There's around 10-15 separate macros that pull out specific info out of a large database. I understand the need to transfer and this is underway. It's an old-school work environment. I'm batting one out trying to change a department. This takes some time to change and I need some stop gaps in the meantime

Comment: Thanks @FoxfireAndBurnsAndBurns, this is a good suggestion. I'll look into it

Comment: @donPablo, I'll update your queries I can update your queries in the question if youre going to look inot this. The refresh on sheet2 would be done a few times a day. Never more than 5. This would be a rolling 30 day span, it would never be empty. I'd prefer to keep it in the same workbook as I have numerous sheets all relating to the central database. Data entered into sheet1 is at random but is approx 20-30 times a day.Can be more sometimes.

Comment: Does Excel crash when users are entering new row(s)? 
Or scrolling to see entire Sheet1?
Or looking at Sheet3::thru::Sheet900?
Or only crash when Sheet2 extract is being run?
Is xls open concurrantly to multiple users?

Does extract Delete Sheet2, & create new Sheet2?
Or does it use existing Sheet2, clear ALL rows, & paste in entire new set of rows.

I need to understand crash reason, & not propose a solution known to crash.
Please attach your extract code as a txt file (not jpg...). What line of code does it crash on?  
Is extract code a module in Sheet1 xlsm? Or separate xlsm?

Comment: I do not see date tags in your original data structure. Have you tried to use `ADODB.Recordset` +  `Range.CopyFromRecordset`?

Comment: Is the main database sheet being opened and closed by other users or is it being left open?

Comment: Goes from "5MB to over 300MB"?   You should post your code on [CodeReview](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As others have mentioned in the comments, using SQL with ADODB is likely a better approach than using PivotTables. I'd also recommend separating your data (Sheet1) from your presentation layer (Excel). E.g. store your data in an *actual* database like Access, SQL Server etc.

However, as you are looking for a stop gap, I figured I could give you an approach that might fill the need temporarily. The code is commented, but feel free to ask questions. You will need to add a reference to `Microsoft Active X Data Object 2.8 or greater` to get this working. [How to add a reference?](https://www.myonlinetraininghub.com/calling-vba-in-add-ins-from-vba-modules)

---

**Early Binding Approach**

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub DisplayView(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
    'Add a reference to Microsoft Active X Data Object 2.8 or greater
    Dim dbConnection  As ADODB.Connection
    Dim dbRecordset   As ADODB.Recordset
    Dim dbCommand     As ADODB.Command
    Dim OutputSheet   As Excel.Worksheet
    Dim dbField       As Variant
    Dim fieldCounter  As Long

    Set dbConnection = New ADODB.Connection
    Set dbRecordset = New ADODB.Recordset
    Set dbCommand = New ADODB.Command
    Set OutputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'Do a quick check to determine the correct connection string
    'if one of these don't work, have a look here --> https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/
    If Left$(ThisWorkbook.FullName, 4) = "xlsm" Then
        dbConnection.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';"
    Else
        dbConnection.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';"
    End If

    'Open the connection and parameterize the query
    dbConnection.Open
    With dbCommand
        .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        'A in B in the text below are the field names in your Sheet 1
        'I wasn't sure what the names of the fields are so I named them as they appeared
        'That being Column A is called A, Column B is called B etc
        .CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet1$] where B in ('A','X') and A >= @StartDate and A < @EndDate"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@StartDate", adDate, adParamInput, , StartDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@EndDate", adDate, adParamInput, , EndDate)
        Set dbRecordset = .Execute
    End With

    'Clear the Output Sheet
    OutputSheet.Cells.Clear

    'Add Headers to output
    For Each dbField In dbRecordset.Fields
        fieldCounter = fieldCounter + 1
        OutputSheet.Cells(1, fieldCounter).Value2 = dbField.Name
    Next

    'Dump the found records
    OutputSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset dbRecordset
    If dbConnection.State = adStateOpen Then dbConnection.Close
End Sub

'Run from here
Public Sub ExampleRunner()
    'Supply the dates you want to filter for
    DisplayView #1/1/2019#, #1/20/2019#
End Sub
```

As requested, here is the **Late Binding Approach** that doesn't require an explicit reference to `Microsoft Active X Data Object`.

```
Option Explicit
Private Const adCmdText As Long = 1
Private Const adDate As Long = 7
Private Const adParamInput As Long = 1
private const adStateOpen as long = 1

Public Sub DisplayView(StartDate As Date, EndDate As Date)
    'Add a reference to Microsoft Active X Data Object 2.8 or greater
    Dim dbField       As Variant
    Dim fieldCounter  As Long
    Dim dbConnection  As Object
    Dim dbRecordset   As Object
    Dim dbCommand     As Object
    Dim OutputSheet   As Excel.Worksheet

    Set dbConnection = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set dbRecordset = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")
    Set dbCommand = CreateObject("ADODB.Command")

    Set OutputSheet = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet2")

    'Do a quick check to determine the correct connection string
    'if one of these don't work, have a look here --> https://www.connectionstrings.com/excel/
    If Left$(ThisWorkbook.FullName, 4) = "xlsm" Then
        dbConnection.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0 Macro;HDR=YES';"
    Else
        dbConnection.connectionstring = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;Data Source=" & _
        ThisWorkbook.FullName & ";Extended Properties='Excel 12.0;HDR=YES';"
    End If

    'Open the connection and parameterize the query
    dbConnection.Open
    With dbCommand
        .ActiveConnection = dbConnection
        .CommandType = adCmdText
        'A in B in the text below are the field names in your Sheet 1
        'I wasn't sure what the names of the fields are so I named them as they appeared
        'That being Column A is called A, Column B is called B etc
        .CommandText = "Select * from [Sheet1$] where B in ('A','X') and A >= @StartDate and A < @EndDate"
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@StartDate", adDate, adParamInput, , StartDate)
        .Parameters.Append .CreateParameter("@EndDate", adDate, adParamInput, , EndDate)
        Set dbRecordset = .Execute
    End With

    'Clear the Output Sheet
    OutputSheet.Cells.Clear

    'Add Headers to output
    For Each dbField In dbRecordset.Fields
        fieldCounter = fieldCounter + 1
        OutputSheet.Cells(1, fieldCounter).Value2 = dbField.Name
    Next

    'Dump the found records
    OutputSheet.Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset dbRecordset
    If dbConnection.State = adStateOpen Then dbConnection.Close
End Sub

'Run from here
Public Sub ExampleRunner()
    'Supply the dates you want to filter for
    DisplayView #1/1/2019#, #1/20/2019#
End Sub
```

Comment: Excellent answer.  I would convert it to late binding because there are multiple user and possibly multiple versions of the ADO library.

Answer (score 0):

Here are some screenshots of the Results of the below mentioned Power Query.  I selected (In Excel 2003) Data->Import External Data->New Database Query
Then, I chose "Excel Files" and added the data I wanted. Make sure to select "is not null" in the query options. I then added the auto sort feature.

[image: ScreenShot1]

[image: ScreenShot2]

You could use a [Power Query](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Import-data-from-external-data-sources-Power-Query-be4330b3-5356-486c-a168-b68e9e616f5a) in the Sheet2 Excel Workbook. [Another link here](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/connect-to-another-workbook-3a557ddb-70f3-400b-b48c-0c86ce62b4f5). This way you could update the data whenever you need to. Then, use SQL to query what you need.

It is pretty simple to use and doesn't take any coding (unless you want to use SQL).

This can be done and then in your other workbook you can do the filtering and sorting.

@ryan-wildry 's post is pretty great (and so is his command text for SQL), but if you do not want to use vba or a database then, you can use this (as well as his SQL text).

An example would be:
  SELECT * FROM [Sheet1$] WHERE Column2='X';

The only problem would be if you have mixed datatypes in the same column.  As can be seen with rows 1 & 4 (they were not able to come across with the query because the values are not the same type. (This is using Excel 2003 so if you have a newer version then, you may be able to check it with that).

I've been doing some research and found that Excel's Power Query will handle mixed data types so, you should be set if you are using Power Query.